# Lenovo Motherboard, FW errors

Tags: windows, motherboard, bios

Where I work we have many lenovo m93 Thinkcentre PCs. In one of them, errors appears right after the lenovo logo. The error sometimes says **"FW status Initializing Error"** or **"FW status Recovery error"**. Right after that an error saying **"(A7) Me FW downgrade MeSpiLock Failed"** appears. We can bypass these errors, sometimes the PC will work correctly and some others it will shutdows shortly after.

We have reset the CMOS, restored bios factory defaults, disabled safeboot, updated the bios, changed the hard drive, replaced memories, changed the PSU, replaced battery, checked processor temps and even tried with another processor. We´ve tried almost everything short of replacing the Motherboard.

The PC is a Thinkcentre M93, Model: a019LM and the motherboard model is lenovo IS8XM (American Megatrends). It has an i3-4i30, stock cooler, no OC.

Does anyone have a suggestion what could be causing this error? Is it Fixable? or should we just give up and replace the Motherboard.

Comment: See if one of these applies to your BIOS: (1) In Advanced -> ME Configuration -> enable both Independent Firmware Recovery (IFR) Feature & ME Firmware Downgrade. (2) If you find in the BIOS an option like "ME FW image re-flash", enable it and reflash the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the MEI firmware by downloading it from below link

http://support.lenovo.com/in/en/downloads/ds040196

it may fix your problem.